# Updating iOS for 64bit and SoundCloud

Tags: ios, 64-bit, soundcloud

I'm updating my iOS app for 64-bit.  The app uses the SoundCloud API, which is not compatible with with 64 bit.

How can I work around this issue?  Do I need to disable SoundCloud on 64-bit machines?  How would one go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct.  You cannot link ARMv7 static libraries against an ARMv8 application.

The two options open to you are:

1. Produce separate 32- and 64-bit builds, in which the 64-bit build doesn't link against the sound cloud API library and associated UI features are disabled.   This is doable, but a bit fiddly.
2. Ship only a 32-bit app.  Ask yourself: is there really anything in your app that will be benefit from 64-bit compatibility?  I suggest if not, you go for this option.

Note that ARMv8 capable iPhones and iPads are capable of running 32bit apps. There is a memory usage penalty in doing so in that both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of shared libraries will be memory resident, but it's not a show-stopper.

Comment: Thanks.  I had, I think wrongly, heard that Apple was requiring all apps 64-bit apps after feb 1st.  But I think they are just requiring the apps be "optimized" for iOS7. (whatever that means :))